# Ajax request for delete image doesnt work in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to delete the image in the preview box, as well as delete it in the database using ajax. Deleting the image in the preview box was successful, but deleting it from the database didn't work.
[image: screenshoot]

here my ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('pro-image').addEventListener('change', readImage, false);
        $(".preview-images-zone").sortable();
        $(document).on('click', '.image-cancel', function() {
            let no = $(this).data('no');
            let idData = $(this).data('id');
            $(".preview-image.preview-show-" + no).remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{url("unit/API/simpan")}}',
                data: {
                    'id': idData
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('success');
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

My Html:

```
<!-- Percobaan Preview -->
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-6">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#pro-image').click()" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Gambar</a>
                                <input type="file" id="pro-image" name="gambarku[]" style="display: none;" class="form-control" multiple>

                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="preview-images-zone offset-md-2 col-md-8">
                            <!-- Gambar Utama  -->
                            <div class="preview-image preview-show-1">
                                <div class="image-cancel" data-no="1">x</div>
                                <div class="image-zone"><img id="pro-img-1" src="{{asset('storage/rumah/'.$rumahku->gambar_rumah)}}"></div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- Gambar Tambahan -->
                            <?php $counter = 2 ?>
                            @foreach($rumahku->gambar as $rows)
                            <div class="preview-image preview-show-{{$counter}}">
                                <div class="image-cancel" data-no="{{$counter}}" data-id="{{$rows->id_gambar}}">x</div>
                                <div class="image-zone"><img id="pro-img-{{$counter}}" src="{{asset('storage/rumah/'.$rows->gambar_unit)}}"></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php $counter++ ?>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>

                        <!-- /preview -->
```

my route

```
Route::post('unit/API/simpan/{id}', 'partner\UnitController@simpanGambar');
```

my controller

```
public function simpanGambar($id)
{
    $gambar = Gambar::find($id);
    $gambar->delete();
}
```

Comment: your `url: '{{url("unit/API/simpan")}}` here `id` is missing

Comment: Helo Kamlesh, thx for replying my message. the id is on the data:{'id': idData}

Comment: it's not working like that

Comment: You defined your route with an ID required in the url. The passed data is something different. As kamlesh said, try to add the Id to the url. Also, would be good if you attach the response you are getting.

Comment: thanks Chuy, i have variable id from let id = $(this).data('id') , cant you tell me how to pass it in ajax

Comment: Check the answer by Kamlesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```php
Route::post('unit/API/simpan', 'partner\UnitController@simpanGambar');
```

and

```php
public function simpanGambar(Request $request)
{
    $gambar = Gambar::find($request->id);
    $gambar->delete();
}
```

---

#### or in ajax

```js
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '{{url("unit/API/simpan")}}' +'/'+ id,  <---------- pass id here
```

Comment: i have variable id from let id = $(this).data('id') , cant you tell me how to pass it in ajax

Comment: thanks Kamlesh, this is work when i change into get Method on the route and ajax. But with the POST method this is doesnt work.

Comment: Please add debug info (response) on your question.

Comment: @kamlesh Paul, i have test it using postman, and this result is 404 .i used this url:http://127.0.0.1:8000/unit/API/simpan/27

Comment: Kamlesh i tried your answer and put this url into my browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/unit/API/simpan and the result is error message "The GET method is not supported for this route". Supported methods: POST. It should be redirect to 404 just like i use the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/unit/store (the default controller store).

Comment: i did not say use `get` you have 2 way to solve this issue which i have mentioned  change controller or in ajax

Comment: Hi Kamlesh, I have follow your method and debug the result is: method 1 (result 404), and method 2 (result 419)

Comment: to fix 419 `data: { 'id': idData, _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}" }` pass  `_token`